# How To Parse String In Java With *

Tags: java

I have a string like this.

```
PER*IP**TE**1234567890*EM*sampleEmail@Email.com
```

How can I parse the string into multiple lines like this in Java?

```
PER
IP
TE
//Empty String
EM
1234567890
sampleEmail@Email.com
```

Comment: Why is there an empty string after `TE`, but not after `IP`? Where has `EM` gone?

Comment: is it giving empty string before the numbers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a regex replacement:

```java
String input = "PER*IP**TE*1234567890*EM*sampleEmail@Email.com";
String output = input.replaceAll("\\*", "\n");
System.out.println(output);
```

This prints:

```
PER
IP

TE
1234567890
EM
sampleEmail@Email.com
```

Answer (score 4):

```
String newstring = string.replace("*", "\n");
System.out.println(newstring);
```

now if you don't want that the empty line show up, use this:

```
String string = "PER*IP**TE**1234567890*EM*sampleEmail@Email.com"
String newstring = string.replaceAll("\\*+","*").replace("*", "\n");
System.out.println(newstring);
```

Comment: yes, sorry, misspell

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`String#split`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-). Since `*` is a regular expression metacharacter, you need to escape it with a backslash or use [`Pattern#quote`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote-java.lang.String-).

```
Arrays.stream("PER*IP**TE**1234567890*EM*sampleEmail@Email.com".split(Pattern.quote("*")))
   .forEach(System.out::println);
```